# How can I find the source for a DLL\PDB in C#?

Tags: c#, dll, pdb-files

I'm attempting to write a C# application that takes built DLLs & PDBs for managed projects and find all the CS\VB files that were used to compile them for cataloging in a database.

Does anyone know of a library that can be used to find all the original source file paths that were used to build a DLL? [ICorDebug](https://github.com/SymbolSource/Microsoft.Samples.Debugging/blob/f820b1c9cfad1f007118bbf8807e9bd10e4047eb/src/debugger/raw/ICorDebugWrappers.cs#L218) might do it, but I can't find where to attach the PDB or get a list of source files.

Comment: You can use [DotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) to disassemble an assembly.

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic: Thanks. I'm actually looking for a way to do it in code. I have ~300 assemblies that I need to look through & don't feel like doing it manually... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Roslyn repo has an app/library called `pdb2xml` that will list the source files in the PDB.

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/tree/master/src/Tools/Source/Pdb2Xml

Comment: Cool! Looking into that it looks like the SymbolDataReader is what I'm looking for... Thanks!

Comment: More specifically... https://github.com/SymbolSource/Microsoft.Samples.Debugging/blob/master/src/tools/pdb2xml/symboldatareader.cs

Comment: @jt000: If you do find a simpler solution, post an answer please (I am personally looking for a non-Roslyn solution)